# Javascript loop unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Here's my function, it is supposed to break the string in groups of 5 lines each but somehow the loop is showing unexpected behavior and alert(data) prints 4 rather than 5 strings. Ami I missing something here?

```
function returnwasset(somedata) {
    alert(somedata);
    var lines = somedata.split('\n');
    var counter = 1;
    var data = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++, counter++) {
        if (counter % 5 === 0) {
            alert(data);
            data = "";
            counter = 1;
        }
        data = data + "\n" + lines[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: edited the question, please read again

Comment: Here's sample data to test
013192002197143
012419001189107
012419002540761
012420002277776
012421009834353
013192002197143
012419001189107
012419002540761
012420002277776
012421009834353
P.S. each number is on new line

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
data=data+"\n"+lines[i];
if(counter%5===0)
{
    alert(data);
    data="";
    counter=1;
}
```

So you first append data and then show that data. Once loop exit's you should check counter variable for last few lines less than 5 like:

```
if (counter < 5) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: This one is printing 9 entries leaving out the last in the second group to the sample of 10 entries, which ideally should've been 2 groups of 5

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function below to display your string in predefined no. of lines. It splits your full string in five lines.

```
function returnwasset(somedata){
    var lines = str.split(' ');
    var wordsperline = parseInt(lines.length / 5);
    var finalline = parseInt(lines.length % 5);
    //alert(lines.length);
    var result = "";
    var counter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(i != 4){
            for(var j = 0; j < wordsperline; j++){
                result += lines[counter] + " ";
                counter++;
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        else{
            for(var k = 0; k < (wordsperline + finalline); k++){
                result += lines[counter] + " ";
                counter++;
            }          
        }
    }

    alert(result);
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/fy9uoj63/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra `counter`, you could use iteration index to do the math.

```js
var testData = '013192002197143 012419001189107 012419002540761 012420002277776 012421009834353 013192002197143 012419001189107 012419002540761 012420002277776 012421009834353'.split(' ').join("\n");

function returnwasset(somedata) {
  alert(somedata);

  var lines = somedata.split("\n");
  var data = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    data += lines[i] + "\n";

    if(i % 5 === 4) {
        alert(data);
        data = "";
    }
  }
}

returnwasset(testData)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of Error** is that `counter` value becomes `2` when the fifth loop is ended as counter is incremented after every loop, so just make `counter = 0` when if condition is met. So when the fifth loop is finished `counter` will a value `1`  :-

```js
var a = '013192002197143\n012419001189107\n012419002540761\n012420002277776\n012421009834353\n013192002197143\n01241900118910\n012419002540761\n012420002277776\n012421009834353';


function returnwasset(somedata) {
    alert(somedata);
    var lines = somedata.split('\n');
    var counter = 1;
    var data = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length+1; i++, counter++) {
        data = data + "\n" + lines[i];
        if (counter % 5 === 0) {
            alert(data);
            data = "";
            counter = 0;
        }        
    }
}

window.onload = returnwasset(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that expands on almas' idea and elminates the need for the `counter` variable or extra code after the loop.

Just replace your `for` loop with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    data += lines[i] + "\n";
    if ((i % 5 === 0 && i > 0) || (i + 1) === lines.length) {
        alert(data);
        data = "";
    }
}
```